# For every integer, some multiple of it is of the form $99 \ldots 900 \ldots 00$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

The goal is to prove that for every positive integer $   z$ there   exists a positive integer $a$ such that $az = 99 \ldots 9900 \ldots 00$.

Let $a = \frac {99 \ldots 9900 \ldots 00}{z}$

That doesn't look right. How do I fix it?

Comment: Don't you have any other assumptions on $a$? Because if not, then $a = 90/z$ is ok.

Comment: Neat problem, But you didn't really do anything.You didn't express the numerator or prove $a$ is an integer.

Comment: Can you prove that any odd number not ending with $5$ has a multiple that is only a row of nines? Because that's the important intermediate step.

Comment: I think this problem is more commonly stated using numbers of the form $1…10…0$. This is equivalent: If some integer multiple of $9a$ has the form $9…90…0$, then the corresponding multiple of $a$ has the form $1…10…0$.

Comment: **Hint:** If $a$ is odd and does not end in $5$, then $\gcd(10,a)=1$. What does this tell you about powers of $10$ modulo $a$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the numbers $u_n=99\cdots9$, where $u_n$ has $n$ nines.

Step 1: They are not all different mod $a$.

Step 2: if $u_n$ and $u_m$ agree mod $a$, with $n>m$, then $u_n-u_m$ is your solution.

Comment: This technique is well-known in the *math puzzle* literature.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a number $k$, lets say it has $k_0$ trailing zeroes and $k_d$ digits that are not trailing zeroes. The trick is to multiply $k$ by $2$ until the number formed by the $k_d$ non-trailing zeroes is odd and does not end in $5$. note that the number formed by $k_d$(we reffer to it as $K_d$) is relatively prime to $10$. Therefore there is a power of $10$ which is congruent to 1 mod $K_d$. So we have a solution to $10^n-1\equiv0 \bmod K^d$. So then it is possible to multiply $k$ by $2$ repeatedly until $K_d$ ends with an odd number that is not $5$. And once this happens we can make $K_d$ of the form $999\dots999$ and once that happens we are done because the trailing zeroes will stay unchanged.
.